# JAVA - Inserting a new line at the next space after 30 characters

Tags: java, string, newline

I have a large block of text (200+ characters in a String) and need to insert new lines at the next space after 30 characters, to preserve words. Here is what I have now (NOT working):

```
String rawInfo = front.getItemInfo(name);
String info = "";
int begin = 0;
for(int l=30;(l+30)<rawInfo.length();l+=30) {
    while(rawInfo.charAt(l)!=' ')
        l++;
    info += rawInfo.substring(begin, l) + "\n";
    begin = l+1;
    if((l+30)>=(rawInfo.length()))
        info += rawInfo.substring(begin, rawInfo.length());
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: So what's the question? Does this work or not?

Comment: Sorry, it is NOT working, I'll edit the question

Comment: By the way, the correct capitalization is "Java," not "JAVA"—but the tag is usually sufficient to let people know what platform you are interested in.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As suggested by kdgregory, using a [`StringBuilder`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) would probably be an easier way to work with string manipulation.

Since I wasn't quite sure if the number of characters before the newline is inserted is the word before or after 30 characters, I opted to go for the word after 30 characters, as the implementation is probably easier.

The approach is to find the instance of the `" "` which occurs at least 30 characters after the current character which is being viewed by using [`StringBuilder.indexOf`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)). When a space occurs, a `\n` is inserted by [`StringBuilder.insert`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert(int,%20char)).

(We'll assume that a newline is `\n` here -- the actual line separator used in the current environment can be retrieved by `System.getProperty("line.separator");`).

Here's the example:

```
String s = "A very long string containing " +
    "many many words and characters. " +
    "Newlines will be entered at spaces.";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);

int i = 0;
while ((i = sb.indexOf(" ", i + 30)) != -1) {
    sb.replace(i, i + 1, "\n");
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Result:

```
A very long string containing many
many words and characters. Newlines
will.
```

I should add that the code above hasn't been tested out, except for the example `String` that I've shown in the code. It wouldn't be too surprising if it didn't work under certain circumstances.

**Edit**

The loop in the sample code has been replaced by a `while` loop rather than a `for` loop which wasn't very appropriate in this example.

Also, the [`StringBuilder.insert`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert(int,%20java.lang.String)) method was replaced by the [`StringBuilder.replace`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace(int,%20int,%20java.lang.String)) method, as Kevin Stich mentioned in the comments that the `replace` method was used rather than the `insert` to get the desired behavior.

Comment: This method worked perfectly, just changed
    sb.insert(i, "\n");
to
    sb.replace(i, i+1, "\n");

Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin Stich: I've updated the sample code -- the for loop wasn't very appropriate in this example, so it was replaced with a while loop.

Comment: it did not restrict the line by number of characters, for e.g. if I changed many to manyyyy the word manyyyy did not appear on the next line instead

Answer (score 4):

Here's a test-driven solution.

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class InsertLinebreaksTest extends TestCase {
    public void testEmptyString() throws Exception {
        assertEquals("", insertLinebreaks("", 5));
    }

    public void testShortString() throws Exception {
        assertEquals("abc def", insertLinebreaks("abc def", 5));
    }

    public void testLongString() throws Exception {
        assertEquals("abc\ndef\nghi", insertLinebreaks("abc def ghi", 1));
        assertEquals("abc\ndef\nghi", insertLinebreaks("abc def ghi", 2));
        assertEquals("abc\ndef\nghi", insertLinebreaks("abc def ghi", 3));
        assertEquals("abc def\nghi", insertLinebreaks("abc def ghi", 4));
        assertEquals("abc def\nghi", insertLinebreaks("abc def ghi", 5));
        assertEquals("abc def\nghi", insertLinebreaks("abc def ghi", 6));
        assertEquals("abc def\nghi", insertLinebreaks("abc def ghi", 7));
        assertEquals("abc def ghi", insertLinebreaks("abc def ghi", 8));
    }

    public static String insertLinebreaks(String s, int charsPerLine) {
        char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
        int lastLinebreak = 0;
        boolean wantLinebreak = false;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            if (wantLinebreak && chars[i] == ' ') {
                sb.append('\n');
                lastLinebreak = i;
                wantLinebreak = false;
            } else {
                sb.append(chars[i]);
            }
            if (i - lastLinebreak + 1 == charsPerLine)
                wantLinebreak = true;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I like to write code test-first, and like to promote the practice; I think I'll be writing more answers this way.  I appreciate the encouragement.

Answer (score 3):

A better solution: copy the string into a StringBuilder so that you can insert / change characters without a lot of substring mucking. Then use the indexOf() method that takes a starting position to find the index to change.

Edit: teh codez:

```
public static String breakString(String str, int size)
{
    StringBuilder work = new StringBuilder(str);
    int pos = 0;
    while ((pos = work.indexOf(" ", pos + size)) >= 0)
    {
        work.setCharAt(pos, '\n');
    }
    return work.toString();
}
```

Comment: I think if you don't increment pos inside the while loop you will accidentally replace every space with \n, causing all lines after the first to have one word.  You need to bump up pos by 30 after each substitution.

Answer (score 1):

I would iterate over the string instead of the 30.  You have to track the 30 though.

psuedocode because this sounds like homework:

```
charInLine=0
iterateOver each char in rawString
    if(charInLine++ > 30 && currChar==' ')
        charInLine=0
        currChar='\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something. Whats wrong with

String s = ...
s = s.substring(0, 30) + s.substring(30).replace(' ', '\n');

This replaces all spaces with newlines starting after character 30.

Its slightly less efficient but for 200 characters it really doesn't matter (that is extremely small for data manipulation).

Bruce

Comment: Then every word after the 30th character would be in its own line.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String s = "A very long string containing " +
"many many words and characters. " +
"Newlines will be entered at spaces.";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
int i = 0;
while ((i = sb.indexOf(" ", i + 30)) != -1) {
    sb.replace(i, i + 1, "\n");
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

this is the correct one i also tried this.